# How to manage change data capture with Teradata?

Tags: teradata, database-replication, cdc, transactional-replication, informatica-powerexchange

I am facing a problem...how to do change data capture with Teradata as a source.
I've found several tools but all of them use Teradata only as a target and sources are "traditional" database systems like Oracle, DB2...

The closest shot I have is Informatica PowerExchange for Teradata. But after reading several pdfs from Informatica I am still unsure if Teradata is possible as a source.

I'm looking for a solution how to capture changes on Teradata warehouse and replicate them somewhere else (hadoop or rdbm).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you researched Teradata's temporal capabilities to see if they would facilitate the CDC behavior you are wishing to implement?